# What species in the Star Trek universe actually independently developed their own warp (FTL) drives?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-tos

There are a few Q&As here that lightly touch on aspects of this subject but are woefully incomplete. Some answers and comments mention the timing (in relation to some other species) of the acquisition of FTL and yet others mention the chronological timing of FTL tech for some species but are scattered across the board and difficult to run down. There's no place where it's comprehensively explained who actually developed their own FTL travel independent of outside influence other than Vulcan and Human. Is there anything in cannon that spells out who actually developed their own warp drives? It would be helpful to have this info in one place for future reference.

Edit:
I understand that compiling a completely comprehensive list of all 180 UFP member species' warp acquisition is near impossible with the limited information available but a summary of what we do know is eminently doable. What prompted the question is that many species apparently acquired the tech through assistance developing it, buying it or stealing it. Just curious who actually developed the tech independently.

Comment: What sorts of sources are you looking for? Just the shows/movies, or would novels and the like be acceptable?

Comment: @Cadence I'm open to all sources of information.

Comment: A) It's not really clear how a lot of the species developed warp drive and b) Accepting answers from "all sources" makes this wicked broad.

Comment: @Valorum I have to admit that I'm not familiar with the EU literature but thought it would be adventitious to not restrict the question so narrowly as to elicit a pithy, "We don't know" answer. If novels and the like can shed some light on the question, I think that value added. There are people here far more knowledgeable about ST lore than I so encourage them to share what they know. In any case the number of self taught FTL developers should be quite small.

Comment: @Morgan - A quick look through my Star Trek library reveals at least 50 book matches for the terms "developed warp", "discovered warp" and "invented warp" and dozens of races who claim that distinction including the Vulcans, the Trill, The Andorians, etc etc

Comment: @Valorum You have an actual Star Trek library? Is that a custom built library or what? Is that online or actual books?

Comment: @Morgan - I have about fifty actual books (mostly factbooks and blueprint archives) and about 1200 ebooks of various types. I manage the latter with a piece of software called Calibre-Ebook

Comment: by general adherence to the Prime Directive, any civilization Starfleet intends to make first contact with has, by definition, progressed to warp travel w/out outside intervention

Comment: Probably the Cytherians and T'kon, I'm guessing.

Comment: @Valorum It's no wonder that your rep has went through the roof in the few years that I've been gone.

Comment: @Morgan - You should see my Star Wars archive. 3000+ books of various types including junior readers, magazines, artbooks, novels, comics, scripts, etc. It's about 200gb

Comment: @Valorum LOL, you need a bigger house.

Comment: @Morgan - Luckily most of it is electronic now. In ye olde days I had entire bookcases devoted to them, but I was able to give hundreds of them away without losing access to the info in them